# Adding a series from a second pandas dataframe on a timeindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with a datetime index

```
2020-12-07  1622
2020-12-07  912
2020-12-07  503
```

```
2020-03-09  1178
2020-03-09  640
2020-03-09  382
```

They will always have the same length (one week)... I need to add the column of df1 to df2. I've tried several things, but the most promising gives me

```py
df1 = df1.assign(bline=pd.Series(df2['num'].values))
```

But it gives me

```
2020-12-07  1622    NaN
2020-12-07   912    NaN
2020-12-07   503    NaN
```

If I simply do: `df['num2'] = df2['num'].values`, it gives me a `SettingWithCopyWarning`... what's the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

`df['num2'] = df2['num'].values` is the way to go. It gives you the warning because your `df` is a slice of another bigger dataframe.

On the other hand

```
df1 = df1.assign(bline=pd.Series(df2['num'].values))
```

doesn't give you the warning because `assign` works on and returns a copy of the slice. But then the `pd.Series(df2['num'].values)` has different index than that of `df1`, so you get all `NaN`. Try:

```
df1 = df1.assign(bline=df2['num'].values)
```